# TYPO3: Save and edit the first & last name of an FE user

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I created an extension with the extension builder which extends the FE user model.

To access the fields, I added the properties inside the extension builder accordingly. This worked great with `city`, `zip`, `address` etc. Unfortunately, you can't enter underscores, so I couldn't add `first_name` and `last_name` to the properties. I added `fname` and `lname` (inside the ext. builder) instead and renamed every `fname` and `lname` to `first_name` and `last_name` by hand (inside the code).

I hope you could follow me until now.

Because the problem is, when adding a FE user through the new action in the frontend, the first and last name won't be saved.
But you can save them without a problem in the backend.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the extbase conventions for field names (lower camel case in model classes, e.g. `$firstName` and `$lastName`). If you do this, they will automatically mapped to the database fields `first_name` and `last_name`, which is also the reason for the restriction in the `extension_builder`. If you don't want to do this, you have to configure the mapping of field name to database field manually in your TypoScript configuration.

Alternatively, you can just use the properties and accessor methods provided by the extbase `FrontendUser` model, from which you inherit - no need to implement that stuff yourself.

Comment: so I should change every `$first_name` to `$firstName`? Should I also do that with the getters and setters?

Comment: Yes, as getters and setters are in some cases used internally to access the fields. They should be named `getFirstName()`, `setFirstName($newFirstName)` and so on (argument names don't matter).

Comment: Also, if you inherit from the extbase model, you should already have all that stuff...

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm now! I just didn't know how to handle an underscore.